# How to extract positive lookbehind of the last occurence of the character in Regex

Tags: regex, string, lookbehind

If I have text like below:

```
Wow [Game Ad] - CHECK - Arabic
```

I trying to extract only `Arabic` from the above text.

I tried `(?<=\-\s)(.*)$` and it returns `CHECK - Arabic` by detecting the first `-` instead of the last occurence of `-`.

Is there a way for extracting the string after the last occurrence of the character for lookbehind?

Comment: Perhaps like this `.*- (.+)` https://regex101.com/r/RiZBJC/1

Comment: Without lookbehind use a capture group: `.*-\s+(\S+)`

Comment: What are the rules you're trying to find? You just want the last word after a hyphen? Then you use `-\s*(\S+)$` and use the capture group.

Comment: And so on and so forth. The PCRE regex is `-\s*\K[^-]*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JST7Cf/1)). You aimed at `(?<=-\s)[^-]+$` I believe.